# Show Notification in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show a grid that involve a label and I want to show this in left-above of another grid.the wpf code(xml) is this :

```
<Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" >
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
```

```
</Grid>
```

How to create this notification when press a button?
I have the C# code for this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Grid.Visibility` on the grid when you push a button. You'll need an qualifying name `x:Name="MyGrid"` and could then set the visibility from code behind.

If you use some approach like MVVM, then you could databind the visibility of the grid to a `bool` in your ViewModel (and use a `DataTrigger` for this instead of the `EventTrigger`).

Edit:

As minimal as it can get:

```
<Grid x:Name="NotifyGrid" Visibility="Hidden">
    <Label Content="Notification" />
</Grid>

<Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50" />
```

And then in the Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     NotifyGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: thanks ,please writing a sample code that I understand successfuly.

Comment: What approach are you on? Code-behind or MVVM?